# jQuery use variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using [jquery.feeds.js](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds/) to aggregate rss feeds and preprocessing the data received with [jsonp.js](https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/). The problem is I can't use the variable `summarize` I've set within the `preprocess` function outside of it. I did set it as a universal variable though so I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Could it be a problem that I'm running multiple JSON requests?

My code:

```
$('#feed').feeds({
    feeds: {
        reuters: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/businessNews'
    },
    max: 2,
    preprocess: function ( feed ) {
        var articleLink = (this.link);
        var summarize = '';

        $.getJSON({
            url: 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=http://clipped.me/algorithm/clippedapi.php?url='+articleLink+'&callback=?',
            corsSupport: true, 
            jsonpSupport: true,

            success: function(data){
              var summarize = data.summary
            }
          });

          alert(summarize);

        this.contentSnippet = summarize

    },
    entryTemplate: '<h3><!=title!></h3><p><!=contentSnippet!></p><i><!=link!></i>'
});
```

And a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tdw7xomk/)

Comment: The 'summarize' variable

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I'm changing the value of 'this.contentSnippet' to the value of 'summarize'

Comment: No you aren't, because that's happening before the __asynchronous__ `getJSON` finishes.

Comment: Ah okay, had never heard of asynchronous getJSON until now.

Comment: It's the (first) __A__ in __AJAX__.

Comment: I just learnt that too! Thanks again.

Comment: This should be re-opened as the issue is not really the ajax result. It seems as it is because it is being used wrongly but the real problem is with the feeds plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a series of errors that are not addressed in the other posts..

- the `preprocess` callback allows for changes in the current object (feed) right before it gets displayed.
  Since the getJSON is an ajax call it will get the results too late. And changing the `contentSnippet` even in the `success` callback will not fix this.
- You use the `$.getJSON` method as if it was `$.ajax`. So you pass it wrong arguments. Just use `$.ajax` for your syntax
- finally to fix the first issue, you need to alter your template a bit so you can find the relevant parts later on (*when the ajax requests complete*) and use the `onComplete` callback instead (*of the feeds plugin*)

All changes together give

```
$('#feed').feeds({
    feeds: {
        reuters: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/businessNews'
    },
    max: 2,
    onComplete: function(entries){ // use onComplete which runs after the normal feed is displayed
        var $this = $(this);
        entries.forEach(function(entry){
            var $self = $this.find('.entry[data-link="'+entry.link+'"]');

            $.ajax({
                url:'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=http://clipped.me/algorithm/clippedapi.php?url='+entry.link,
                corsSupport: true, 
                jsonpSupport: true,     
                success: function(data){
                    // add the results to the rendered page
                    $self.find('.snippet').html( data.summary );
                }
              });
        });   
    }, // change the template for easier access through jquery
    entryTemplate: '<div class="entry" data-link="<!=link!>"><h3><!=title!></h3><p class="snippet"><!=contentSnippet!></p><i><!=link!></i></div>'
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pc7s2bmr/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to research your answer. I really appreciate it. This works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this

```
$('#feed').feeds({
    feeds: {
        reuters: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/businessNews'
    },
    max: 2,
    preprocess: function ( feed ) {
        var articleLink = (this.link);
        var summarize = '';

        var that = this;

        $.getJSON({
            url: 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=http://clipped.me/algorithm/clippedapi.php?url='+articleLink+'&callback=?',
            corsSupport: true,
            jsonpSupport: true,

            success: function(data){
                that.contentSnippet = data.summary
            }
        });

    },
    entryTemplate: '<h3><!=title!></h3><p><!=contentSnippet!></p><i><!=link!></i>'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Mathletics is correct. Do this...

```js
$('#feed').feeds({
    feeds: {
        reuters: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/businessNews'
    },
    max: 2,
    preprocess: function ( feed ) {
        var articleLink = (this.link);
        var summarize = '';
      var _this = this;

        $.getJSON({
            url: 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=http://clipped.me/algorithm/clippedapi.php?url='+articleLink+'&callback=?',
            corsSupport: true, 
            jsonpSupport: true,

            success: function(data){
               _this.contentSnippet = data.summary
            }
          });

          alert(summarize);
    },
    entryTemplate: '<h3><!=title!></h3><p><!=contentSnippet!></p><i><!=link!></i>'
});
```

Comment: I just tried it having edited '$this' to 'this' and it didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to add the $. Corrected the post.